# How to use iter and next in a function to return a list of peaks?

Tags: python-3.x

**Problem:**

I need to define a peaks function which passed to an iterable as parameter, by computing this iterable, the function should return a list of peaks. The only data structure that I can create is the list is returning; use no intermediate data structures to help the computation: e.g., I cannot create a list with all the values in the iterable. Note that I also cannot assume the argument is indexable, nor can I compute len for it: it is just iterable.

For example:

```
peaks([0,1,-1,3,8,4,3,5,4,3,8]) returns [1, 8, 5].
```

This result means the values 1, 8, and 5 are strictly bigger than the values immediately preceding and following them.

```
def peaks(iterable):
    l=[]
    i=iter(iterable)
    v=next(i)
    try:
        while True:
            if v>next(iter(iterable)):
                l.append(v)
            v=next(i)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return l
```

Calling these should give me:

```
peaks([0,1,-1,3,8,4,3,5,4,3,8]) --> [1,8,5]
peaks([5,2,4,9,6,1,3,8,0,7]) -->[9,8]
```

But I am getting:

```
peaks([0,1,-1,3,8,4,3,5,4,3,8]) --> [1, 3, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 8]
peaks([5,2,4,9,6,1,3,8,0,7]) --> [9, 6, 8, 7]
```

Please help me with this problem, I have spent so much time on it and am making no progress on it. And, I don't know how to write the if statement to check the values immediately preceding and following. Any helps would be great! Actual codes would be really appreciated since my English is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def peaks(L):
    answer = []
    a,b,c = itertools.tee(L, 3)
    next(b)
    next(c)
    next(c)
    for first, second, third in zip(a,b,c):
        if first <= second >= third:
            answer.append(second)
    return answer

In [61]: peaks([0,1,-1,3,8,4,3,5,4,3,8])
Out[61]: [1, 8, 5]

In [62]: peaks([5,2,4,9,6,1,3,8,0,7])
Out[62]: [9, 8]
```